# onClickHandler sometimes work, sometimes not - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

The **onClickHandler** in the following code, in this component, **'SearchResult'**, sometimes work and sometimes not.

I can't figure out any logic that can explain why it works when it works, and why it's not working, when it's not working.

I've put a debugger inside the onClickHandler, at the beginning of it, and when it's not working, it doesn't get to the debugger at all - what indicates that the function sometimes isn't even called, and I can't figure out why.

Furthermore, I've tried to move all the code in function to the onClick, inline, but then, it's not working at all.

In addition, I've tried to use a function declaration instead of an arrow function, and it still behaves the same - sometimes it works, and sometimes it's not...

[This is the site](https://obrm-hero-weather.netlify.app), you can see the behavior for yourself, in the search box.

[This is the GitHub repository](https://github.com/obrm/ori-baram-25-04-2021)

### [Here you can see a **video** demonstrating how it's not working, except for one time it did work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkB5Vrlzhug)

**Please help.**

#### The problematic component:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { getWeatherRequest } from '../redux/weather/weatherActions'
import { GENERAL_RESET } from '../redux/general/generalConstants'

const SearchResult = ({ Key, LocalizedName, setText }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: GENERAL_RESET })
    dispatch(
      getWeatherRequest({
        location: Key,
        cityName: LocalizedName,
      })
    )
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <Col className='suggestion' onClick={onClickHandler}>
      {LocalizedName}
    </Col>
  )
}

export default SearchResult
```

#### This is the parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { getAutoCompleteResultsRequest } from '../redux/autoComplete/autoCompleteActions'
import { AUTO_COMPLETE_RESET } from '../redux/autoComplete/autoCompleteConstants'
import SearchResult from './SearchResult'

const SearchBox = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const autoComplete = useSelector((state) => state.autoComplete)
  const { results } = autoComplete

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === '') {
      dispatch({ type: AUTO_COMPLETE_RESET })
      setText('')
    }
    setText(e.target.value)
    dispatch(getAutoCompleteResultsRequest(e.target.value))
  }

  const onBlurHandler = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: AUTO_COMPLETE_RESET })
      setText('')
    }, 100)
  }

  return (
    <div className='search-box'>
      <Form inline>
        <div className='input-group search-md search-sm'>
          <input
            type='search'
            name='q'
            value={text}
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            onBlur={onBlurHandler}
            placeholder='Search Location...'
            className='mr-sm-2 ml-sm-3 form-control'
          />
        </div>
      </Form>
      <div className='search-results'>
        {results &&
          results.map((result) => {
            return (
              <SearchResult key={result.Key} {...result} setText={setText} />
            )
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBox
```

Comment: Hi, I tested the input on your website. Could you please describe the expected behavior?

Comment: It should simply display the weather of the selected city from the auto complete list

Comment: Here you can see that it worked one time, and in the other times it didn't - 
https://youtu.be/EkB5Vrlzhug

Comment: Here you can see that most of the time it worked https://youtu.be/MTbRYc7MKjI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with your code and it looks like a possible solution may be the following addition in the SearchResult.js:

```
const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
...
```

**After some tests**

Please remove the `onBlurHandler`. It seams to fire ahaed of the `onClickHandler` of the result.

Comment: It looks like it improved the situation, but still there are hiccups - mainly when choosing the first suggestion.

Comment: Here you can clearly see that it still happens https://youtu.be/pOyFOFa3JmM

Comment: One thing that makes me head scratch is that beside it is not firing the event the input box still gets cleared. So there is an event attached but it is unclear which one.

Comment: I set the onBlurHandler to fire off after 100 milliseconds. I will try to increase it to 200 milliseconds...

Comment: Ok, this is the solution. Increasing the timeout for this event.

Comment: I set the onBlurHandler to fire off after 300 milliseconds now, and it seems it fixed the issue.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you put `console.log(e.target.value)` inside the `onChangeHandler`,
   press again search results and make sure that one of it doesn't working and show us the console.
2. In `searchResult` component print to the console `LocalizedName` as well

Comment: Here in the [screen capture](https://youtu.be/WyNVg0hHMow) you can see I did everything you asked me to do.
It worked most of the times, except for one time it didn't.
[Here is the relevant file](https://github.com/obrm/ori-baram-25-04-2021/blob/master/src/components/SearchResult.js) - and as you can see, the e.target.value has no meaning in this case.